# Moment.js creates a new date incorrectly

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following line of javascript using MomentJS

```
var date = moment('20/04/20000', 'DD/MM/YYYY'); //notice year twenty thousand
alert(date.format()); // alerts "2000-04-20T00:00:00+01:00"
```

If I change the format to `DD/MM/YYYYY` it works as expected, except of course if I enter a 6 digit year. I know this is arbitrary, but it bothers me. How do I use a format that will expect any amount of digits in the year?

Comment: I don't think you can. Unless you modify the plugin to do so.

Comment: what r u trying to achieve ?

Comment: you probably cannot.

Comment: test your issue with this code `alert(moment(testDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));`

Comment: You can ask yourself 'why?'. If it is because you _believe_ it should, stop trying. If you are creating a game in which the period is the year 20000 and dates are for some reason relevant, just start working from the year 2000 and add 18.000 to every year value. Or don't use momentJS

Comment: @Mosselman Why? Because business requirement states: "Date of birth should not allow over 100 years of age" and thus the test department rejected check in because the validation code passes the invalid value since the Moment date object is not containing the value entered.

Comment: @Mou thanks, what am I testing for using that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like moment ignores any extra format specfiers.  So you can just use as many Y's as you expect you'll need for your max date.  For example this code tells moment to expect 10 digit years:

```
moment('20/04/20000', 'DD/MM/YYYYYYYYYY').format();
```

but it's return value looks like what you're expecting, 5 digit year:

"20000-04-20T00:00:00-04:00"

This is not a documented feature, and I'd be very careful about this code as you use future moment updates.  Protect this code with unit tests for sure.

Comment: Thanks Travis. This is not ideal, since (as you say) it is not entirely stable. Also, technically the user could always still enter one more digit than what I  expect. "How many Y's do I expect?" ==  "How long is a piece of string?"

Comment: What type of software are you writing that needs to have dates 10 billion years into the future?

Comment: You are missing the point. I don't need that. In fact I specifically need it NOT to allow that. So if the user types that it should say: "That's not allowed". Currently, if the user types a larger number it is assumed to be the smaller number, so my validation assumes that it is valid (which it is not)

Comment: Ok wait, if I use 5 digit format (DD/MM/YYYYY), the incorrect assumption will still be 5 digits (even if 6 or more were entered), so the validation will serve it's purpose. Thanks for your help.